# Concurrent limitations when querying wit.ai

Tags: wit.ai

anybody can tell me wit.ai query concurrency？Our website traffic will be more than 50,000 a day，I need to know how many concurrency a wit.ai app can handle，thanks

Answer (score 1):

I asked them some months ago, they said:

> We have no hard limit on concurrent API calls, and one of the
>   developers did perform some load test at about 400 QPS.